# I want to order my data from newest to oldest using Cloud Firestore in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort my data from oldest to newest from Cloud Firestore this is my code:

```
  private void loadNotesList() {
    firestoreDB.collection("keluhan")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<keluhanModel> notesList = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                            keluhanModel note = doc.toObject(keluhanModel.class);
                            note.setId(doc.getId());
                            notesList.add(note);
                        }

                        mAdapter = new adapterKeluhan(notesList, getApplicationContext(), firestoreDB);
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I have tried to use .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) but it didn't do anything it just a white page in my Android application.

This is my database:

[image: screenshot database]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to order your results by date, you should use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference keluhanRef = rootRef.collection("keluhan");
Query dateQuery = keluhanRef.orderBy("timeStamp", Direction.ASCENDING);
dateQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Calling:

```
.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

Will never work since your property name is `timeStamp` and **not** `date`.

Comment: but i face a problem again, it sort by time but sort by their id too,  how to make the sort only by the time and not by id

Comment: Without an explicit to `.orderBy("NIM", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)` or whatever your property name is called, there is no order on that. If you have such a call, simply remove it.